# Disable Mouse Acceleration In Ubuntu

Tags: mouse

So this is my first post on the Ubuntu forums and probably my most important question that I will ever ask. I've read around about disabling mouse acceleration in Ubuntu, I'm sure that most of them work fine but I'm having a little problem. Bear in mind I am very new to Linux and I know little to none about commands.

The problem is when I put xinput list into the terminal, my mouse get's outputted in 3 different places.

```
alan@alan:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard                    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse       id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard                    id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse       id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So when I want to disable the acceleration on the mouse, which one am I meant to use? Because using id numbers, which change at every restart, is not going to work out because I would love to make some file to execute the mouse acceleration disabling commands at every startup automatically. Will the commands below be successful at disabling the mouse acceleration?

```
xinput set-prop 'Name' 'Device Accel Profile' -1

xinput set-prop 'Name' 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems every year or so my touch-pad acceleration turns itself on again on Ubuntu. This year the workaround was as follows:

Install some new software:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput libinput-tools
```

Display properties:

```
xinput list-props 12
```

Reduce sensitivity:

```
xinput set-prop 12 141 0.800000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.800000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.800000
```

Disable finger scrolling:

```
xinput set-prop 12 286 0, 0, 0
```

I should add you need to put these commands in `~/.profile` to have them on by deFault. Also the "magic number" 12 above comes from the output of the `xinput list` command:

```
 xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Hope it helps someone else!